# What is a 7 or more pin flexible connector that fits in a 12.5 mm gap?

Tags: connector, embedded, flexible

I am making a very compact embedded clamshell device. it has two boards, connected by one hinge.

I only have a 12.5 mm gap where I can put a connector, and I can't really trim the number of lines down any further. what kind of connector would fit this description?

Comment: Do you mean that the cable has to fit through a 12.5 mm gap? Have you seen flat flex cable? There is no connector on the cable itself that would otherwise need a bigger gap to fit through.

Comment: I assume that 12.5mm is board to board clearance, do you have any surface area constraints?

Comment: i mean the only spot i can put a connector is 12.5 mm from edge to edge.

Comment: "from edge to edge". From what edge to what edge? Please make a sketch and show us what you mean. A picture is worth 1000 words.

Comment: Does the connector need to turn with the hinge? If not, what turns with the hinge? Cable? Wires?

Comment: ok, little update, i made some modifacations, all it needs is 6 pins now. yes, it does go through the hinge.

Comment: @RBaker You're going to have to help us here with the mechanics of the configuration. Would a dimensioned stick-figure diagram edited into the question really be too much to ask? Seeing as you would like us to help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

FPC cable connectors are normally less than 10mm height.
If your circuit connection requires a little bigger current, you can use 24pin like FPC cable with enough pin counts and use multiple wires to deliver high currents.